# How to Use Variables in CTE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

**Objective**: I am trying to create a dynamic deduplication stored procedure.

**Background**: I typically perform deduplication with CTE statements and it works great.

**Issue**: I need to be able to add variables in the CTE, however this is not possible.

**Method**: Below is what I would LIKE to do. It works with variables evaluated.

```
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(MAX) = N'MySchemaName';
DECLARE @TableName varchar(MAX) = N'MyTableName';
DECLARE @columnNames varchar(MAX) = (SELECT
                                         STRING_AGG ('['+E.COLUMN_NAME+']', ',') 
                                     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS E
                                     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName);

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        @columnNames,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY @columnNames ORDER BY @columnNames)
    FROM 
        '[' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + ']'
) 
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1;
```

How can I refactor this to get it to work? Thanks

Comment: Use dynamic sql: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Parameters can only be used for values, not for other parts of the query